# Unable to resolve module react-native-navbar

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-router-flux, side-menu

I am not able to install the component cause I get this error:

```
npm install react-native-side-menu
Rdemo@0.0.1 /home/mss/Desktop/cakenew25_aug/MagentoLatest/Rdemo
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.0.0-alpha.6
`-- react-native-side-menu@0.20.1 

npm WARN react-native-selectbox@0.1.2 requires a peer of react@>15.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-static-container@1.0.1 requires a peer of react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.
```

I am trying to implement side menu in my react native demo. I am newbie to this platform and self learner. **i am using react-native-router-flux** architecture in this demo.

i got example for side menu implementation from below link :-

https://reacttuts.blogspot.in/2016/06/side-menu-component-for-react-native.html?showComment=1496152015774#c5969922046557572516

**I tried following commands to get rid of this error , but no success** :-

```
npm install npm@latest -g
npm prune
npm install --save react@16.0.0-alpha.6
```

**React native version info :-**

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.44.0
```

**Here is my Package.json :-**

```
{
  "name": "Rdemo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.44.0",
    "react-native-check-box": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-flexi-radio-button": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.38.0",
    "react-native-selectbox": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-web-service-handler": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.2",
    "jest": "20.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**npm detail :-**

```
npm list --depth=0
Rdemo@0.0.1 /home/mss/Desktop/cakenew25_aug/MagentoLatest/Rdemo
+-- babel-jest@20.0.3
+-- babel-preset-react-native@1.9.2
+-- jest@20.0.3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.0.0-alpha.6
+-- react-native@0.44.0
+-- react-native-check-box@1.0.4
+-- react-native-drawer@2.3.0
+-- react-native-easy-toast@1.0.6
+-- react-native-flexi-radio-button@0.2.0
+-- react-native-router-flux@3.39.2
+-- react-native-selectbox@0.1.2
+-- react-native-vector-icons@4.2.0
+-- react-native-web-service-handler@1.0.2
`-- react-test-renderer@16.0.0-alpha.6

npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@>15.0, required by react-native-selectbox@0.1.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0, required by react-static-container@1.0.1


Node version :- v6.9.1
npm version :- v3.10.8
```

**Here is the screenshot of my error :-**

[image]

Any Help ,
Thanks

Comment: try to use yarn to install the package

Comment: @KimHau , do you mean yarn add react@16.0.0-alpha.6 ?

Comment: @KimHau , yarn add react-native-side-menu ?

Comment: yea yarn add react-native-side-menu

Comment: getting this error :- ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'add'

Answer (score 1):

react-native-side-menu require react 16.0.0-alpha.6 to work. 
Do this, find the **package.json** file in your project folder located in the root directory. open it and find **react** (in the dependencies dictionary), edit the value to "16.0.0-alpha.6", save it and then

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install --save
```

this will install all the dependencies found in your package.json, and now the required react version will be installed. This procedure can be used for any package.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's not able to find the module in your project directory, may be this is because the package got installed globally, do this, go to your project directory, remove all node modules and then npm install --save. and from your project folder, react-native run-android. Let me know what output you get

Comment: should i remove node module folder ? or the folders inside it ?

Comment: the entire node module folder, do rm -rf node_modules/ from your root directory, it'll do the job

Comment: Still getting same issue , i run both the commands rm -rf node_modules/ and then npm install --save.

Comment: Okay, may be the library didn't get linked properly. try  react-native link react-native-side-menu

Comment: I don't think so.. what happened when you tried to link? did it link successfully?

Comment: i got this :- 
Scanning 571 folders for symlinks in /home/mss/Desktop/cakenew25_aug/MagentoLatest/Rdemo/node_modules (5ms)
{ Error: Cannot find module '/home/mss/Desktop/cakenew25_aug/MagentoLatest/Rdemo/node_modules/react-native-side-menu/package.json'

Comment: was not able to find module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145514/discussion-between-bk7-and-siddharth).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with to install with sudo. I think its a kind of permission issue.

Comment: Hello @Anuj , yes i tried with Sudo too , it was still giving same error.